# Read a free format input file

Tags: r, input, file-io

I have an R code divided in multiple scripts. The results of the code depend on some parameters included in the main script. The script is not too long (200 lines), but still, instead than having parameters dispersed inside the script, I think it would be tidier to have them all in a nice input file. The problem is that, while it's easy to read dataframe-like files into R, i.e., files such that each column has one type, I'm not sure how to read a free format file. The format is of the type

```
var_1 contents of var_1
var_2 contents of var_2
.
.
.
```

For example:

```
db_filename  "goofy.csv"
exe_filename "cal_code.exe"
calibration_parameters "Cd" "fn" "fm"
tests "T1" "T2" "T4" "T9"
test_type "V"
speed   2310
flow_rate 2.238
```

The parameters can be specified in a fixed order (so that `db_filename` is always in the first row). A solution where each variable can be in any row, as long as it's in only **ONE** row, would be better, as long as this doesn't make the file read code needlessly complicated. What's mandatory is that the format must be "free", where with "free" I mean that I don't want to be forced to have the `flow_rate` variable (for example) starting always at column 10 (for example). I also mean that the length of parameters which are not scalar, must be variable: for example, `calibration_parameters` and `tests` are vector, as you can see. The file read code must be able to cope with 3 calibration parameters, 4, 5, etc.
Finally, I used spaces to separate elements in this file, but I can accept solutions where other separators are used, if this simplifies the task. Can you help me read such a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using colons:

```
db_filename:"goofy.csv"
exe_filename:"cal_code.exe"
calibration_parameters:"Cd" "fn" "fm"
tests:"T1" "T2" "T4" "T9"
test_type:"V"
speed :  2310
flow_rate:2.238
```

I think something like this would work for you?

```
library(tidyverse)
df = as_tibble( t( read.csv("playing-around.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ":", strip.white = TRUE) %>% tidyr::separate("V2", sep = " ", into = as.character(c(1:10) ) ) ) )
#I used 1:10, but just set it beyond your maximum option list size and this should work
#move the first row to the column names
colnames(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))
df = tail(df, -1)
```

You can then access your set of options as i.e. a character vector:
`options = na.omit(df$db_filename)`.

Comment: I'll try the code later, but in meantime could you please explain what is the meaning of the `"V2"` string in the `separate` expression?

Comment: V2 is the default name for the second column which comes from ```read.csv``` when you don't specify ```col.names```.  We separate on the second column which is defined by the colon.

Comment: The last line should be `tail(df, -1)`, not `head(df, -1)`. The results are fair but not great..the number of whitespaces before and after each colon greatly alter the results of the read operation. For example, compare the penultimate row, `speed :  2310`, with the last row `flow_rate:2.238`. The penultimate row is transformed in a column whose name is not `speed` but `\`speed \`` (!!), and whose first two elements are empty, while the last row is correctly transformed in a column named `flow_rate`, whose first element is `2.238` and it's the only empty element. Of course, forcing the [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] user to never leave whitespaces before and after the colons will result in a correctly read data frame, but this is not exactly what I intended for free format. I thought it could be possible to ignore multiple whitespaces, but maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I have added the strip.white option to read.csv.  I believe this solves your objection.